# ByteArrayBuffer throws IndexOutOfBounds Exception - cannot get the cause

Tags: android, arrays, byte, indexoutofboundsexception

I am receiving a ByteArray in Android through LocalBroadcastManager. It works fine, however I send it in chunks.

When I want to merge back the chunks, I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
else if (message.equals(BtConstants.BtStateUpdates.BT_UPDATE_STATE_RXRAW_COMPLETE.getString())) {
    Log.i(TAG, "length [" + Integer.toString(picRaw.length()) + "] / capacity [" + Integer.toString(picRaw.capacity()) + "]");
    Log.i(TAG,"append" + Integer.toString(intent.getExtras().getByteArray(BtConstants.btBytePayload).length));              
    picRaw.append(intent.getExtras().getByteArray(BtConstants.btBytePayload), picRaw.length(), 
    intent.getExtras().getByteArray(BtConstants.btBytePayload).length);                 
    String s = "";
    try {
        s = new String(picRaw.buffer(), "US-ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "RCVD RAW: " + s);   
}
```

And here is the error. Notice at first it appends the smaller 650 bytes, but then it fails when appending a bigger value.

```
**10-25 11:21:40.670: I/BluetoothService(9537): length [0] / capacity [15000]

10-25 11:21:40.675: I/BluetoothService(9537): append665**

Works FINE so far

10-25 11:21:40.680: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(9537): readNative

10-25 11:21:40.680: I/BluetoothService(9537): RCVD RAW: �..edited out for brevity.�

10-25 11:21:40.680: D/BluetoothService(9537): Rcvd broadcast: com.test.ppt.bt_state_raw_connected 

**10-25 11:21:40.695: I/BluetoothService(9537): length [665] / capacity [15000]

10-25 11:21:40.695: I/BluetoothService(9537): append5320

10-25 11:21:40.695: D/AndroidRuntime(9537): Shutting down VM

10-25 11:21:40.695: W/dalvikvm(9537): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3c1f8)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException**

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer.append(ByteArrayBuffer.java:68)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at com.test.ppt.btService.BluetoothService$1.onReceive(BluetoothService.java:217)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)

10-25 11:21:40.730: E/AndroidRuntime(9537):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The initial capacity is 15000 - which should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/ByteArrayBuffer.html).
ByteArrayBuffer.append works differently than I expected.
Quoting from this new documentation:

> **void    append(char[] b, int off, int len)**
>
> ```
>       Appends len chars to this buffer from the given source array starting at index off.
> ```

Starting at index off in the char[]b. Append is always done at the end of the ByteArrayBuffer.

Therefor my code should look like this:

```
picRaw.append(intent.getExtras().
    getByteArray(BtConstants.btBytePayload), picRaw.length(), 
        intent.getExtras().getByteArray(BtConstants.btBytePayload).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
                s = new String(picRaw.buffer(), "US-ASCII");
            } 
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I hope the above code will help you.